# Where is the most "realistic" CDP-S100's volume level that is closest to real acoustic piano?

Tags: piano, technique, practice, digital-piano

As a very beginner I've bought the CDP-S100. It seems enough at least for first year of leisurely learning.
But while practicing, I noticed that I apply different force to keys depending on volume level set on my piano, because I unconsciously try to reach the same sound volume. For example, when I practice at night with 20% volume level set, I hit keys way more intensively than at midday with 50% volume level set, or then when I use my headphones.

So, the question is - what volume level should I set to make it sound as if it were an acoustic piano, with the similar loudness/hitforce ratio? 50%? 100%? I'm aware that there are no exact standards here, but anyway I want to have some approximate basis to keep in mind.

Unfortunately I have no ability to compare it to acoustic piano in the same room now, so maybe someone's already done such experiment? :)

Thanx a lot in advance for any clue :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing that particular model, I'd guess you probably need "full volume" to properly match an acoustic.

If you ever try actually accompanying people live in a 'gig' situation, you will quickly discover a digital piano just cannot reach the levels you can with an acoustic, without further amplification.
Pianos are pretty loud.

That doesn't actually mean you have to use it on full all the time - because if you were actually in a gig situation, you'd probably be in a larger or noisier space & you would need the extra level.
In the living room… not so much. I'd drop the levels to what you are comfortable listening at for your particular playing style of any given piece. Don't let the volume slider affect your playing.

Comment: The point is that the most comfortable level for me is "as quiet level as possible" :) And I'm afraid I can hit my keys way more than it should be done because of it :)

Comment: Just checked in my studio - I have several k'bds set up, and a studio acoustic piano. A Roland (2x 7w, same size speakers) sounds about the same as the acoustic piano when the vol. pot. is full on. Which agrees with your idea. +1.

Comment: ...so, according to your answer, seems like it would be better to set the highest level to push myself to control the volume more attentively at the beginning of learning. Am i right?

Comment: Hitting keys hard rarely does any damage - to the piano - maybe to one's ears! Leaving the volume up high will make you become far more discening as to how you press the keys - a good thing.

Comment: @Tim thanx a lot! 
I guess my neighbours won't sleep tonight :)

Comment: That's when you start learning to play gently too.

Comment: For a little light nocturne, sure… but if you're getting your best Jerry Lee Lewis impression down pat, you probably need to pull that slider back a ways;) That's why I said don't let the slider dictate how hard you play.